# Navigating from silverlight application to external webpage

Tags: silverlight

I needed a hyperlink that looked like a button so I created a button that navigates on click using this

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), "_blank");
```

This works fine when I am in a web browser however when I install the silverlight application to my desktop I get the error below.

```
The DOM/Scripting bridge is disabled
```

I've read a few things online and I found that there is a "enablehtmlaccess" parameter that I can change that will allow this to work.  However, I don't have access to the html for this page.  Is there any other way I can do this.  It works for hyperlink controls so I imagine there has to be a way to do it with a button.

Thanks for the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = new Uri("http://dotnetperls.com/");
    NavigateToUri(url);

}
public class MyHyperlinkButton : HyperlinkButton
{
    public void ClickMe()
    {
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
private void NavigateToUri(Uri url)
{
    if (App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        MyHyperlinkButton button = new MyHyperlinkButton();
        button.NavigateUri = url;
        button.TargetName = "_blank";
        button.ClickMe();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(url, "_blank");
    }
}
```